# How to keep the value of a global variable next time the script is run?

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript file, that's called from another, which has some global variables defined, something like `Dim var="whatever"` outside of every function and sub. Those variables might change, maybe an instruction like `var="whatever2"` and their new values might be used in some calls that the other VBScript file does. But problem is that everytime the file is called their values are reset to the ones that are shown in the place where the global values are defined, so it takes the same values again.

I see two ways to solve this: One to create a text file where all actual correct values are written and then when the script is called read them from that text file, although I guess there has to be a better way. The other is to keep on using parameters for the calls, but this would likely complicate the application a lot, that's precisely the reason to use global variables, so I don't think it's a real option. I also think getting to set the values in a function wouldn't help much as they would be reseted afterwards anyway.

Any idea on how something like what I'm telling could be done?

Answer (score 2):

Global variables only live as long as their process is running. If you need to persist the values of these variables so they're available when the script is run again later on you need to store them elsewhere.

The canonical methods are saving the values to a file:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\mystate.txt")
f.Write "var1=" & var1
f.Write "var2=" & var2
...
f.Close
```

or to the registry:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\mystate\var1", var1, "REG_SZ"
sh.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\mystate\var2", var2, "REG_DWORD"
...
```

However, if you only need them to be available during the current user session, you could also use the volatile environment:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set env = sh.Environment("VOLATILE")
env("mystate_var1") = var1
env("mystate_var2") = var2
...
```

The volatile environment is only available for the current user and will vanish when the user logs off.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using COM objects as your slave objects.

Script Components make vbscript COM objects. WSF script files hold many scripts in one file and can reference other files.

From Help

> Windows® Script Components provide you with an easy way to create powerful, reusable COM components in script. You create script components using any scripting language that supports the Microsoft® ActiveX® Scripting interfaces. Script languages that support these interfaces include JScript, Microsoft® Visual Basic® Scripting Edition (VBScript), PERLScript, PScript, and Python.
>
> **COM Support**
>
> This new script component technology supports common types of COM components, such as Automation, and is extensible with add-ons such as DHTML behaviors.
>
> **Script Components**:
>
> Are small and efficient.
>
> Are easy to create, maintain, and deploy.
>
> Provide the ability to create COM components.
>
> Provide access to a broad range of system services.
>
> Using script components, you can create COM components for a variety of tasks, such as performing middle-tier business logic, accessing and manipulating database data, adding transaction processing to applications, and adding interactive effects to a Web page using DHTML Behaviors

and wsf files.

> A Windows script (*.wsf) file is a text document containing Extensible Markup Language (XML) code. It incorporates several features that offer you increased scripting flexibility. Because Windows script files are not engine-specific, they can contain script from any Windows Script compatible scripting engine. They act as a container.
>
> Additional Features
>
> .wsf files support  You can
>
> Include statements
>
> Incorporate functions from VBScript or JScript files into your Windows Script Host project.
>
> Multiple engines
>   Use more than one scripting language per file.
>
> Type libraries
>   Add constants to your code.
>
> Tools
>
> Edit files with any XML editor.
>
> Multiple jobs in one file
>
> Store all of your code in a single location